# print header-value from dataframe matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a matrix obtained with pandas.dataframe in this way:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
x = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus)
df_tfidf = pd.DataFrame(x.toarray(),columns=tfidf.get_feature_names())
```

It seems like the matrix below:

[image]

My matrix has more columns and more rows. It has 7180 rows and 10390 columns. Is there a way to print the header of col and its value is this value is greater than 0 ? somethink like this `and: 0.511859, document: 0.46,0.68 ..`

I tried in this way but it take a lot of time:

```
for col in df_tfidf.columns:
   for row in df_tfidf.index:
     if df_tfidf[col][row] > 0:
        print str(df_tfidf[col][row]) + ' ' + col.encode('utf8')
```

Is there a way to do this faster ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: i want to iterate the matrix to obtain just the word and its tfidf value. But it is to big

Comment: By `tfidf` values you mean positive values for each column, right? And do you need to store this values maybe in some dictionary or just wants to print them?

Comment: yes they are all positive value. I want to save it in a sort of dictionary `word: value`. I'm tring to work on the answer given by chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *boolean masking* with numpy array to filter positive values inside a `dict` comprehension:

```
r = {c: s[s > 0] for c, s in zip(df, df.T.to_numpy())}
```

EDIT: `DataFrame.to_numpy()` is available in pandas version >= `0.24`, if you are using pandas version below `0.24` then use:

```
r = {c: s[s > 0] for c, s in zip(df, df.T.values)}
```

Example:

```
# Sample dataframe
       col0      col1      col2
0  0.392938 -0.427721 -0.546297
1  0.102630  0.438938 -0.153787
2  0.961528  0.369659 -0.038136
3 -0.215765 -0.313644  0.458099
4 -0.122856 -0.880644 -0.203911

# Result
{'col0': array([0.39293837, 0.10262954, 0.9615284 ]),
 'col1': array([0.43893794, 0.36965948]),
 'col2': array([0.45809941])}
```

Comment: I tried with you method but I get `DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'`

Comment: @Lx2pwn Whats your pandas version? If lower than `0.24` then you can replace `to_numpy()` with `values`..

Comment: it is 0.22.0 on python 2.7

Comment: `to_numpy()` is introduced in pandas version `0.24`..Try with `.values`

Comment: now i get `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

Comment: it works perfectly with r = {c: s[s > 0] for c, s in zip(df, df.T.values)} in 13 second with a dataframe matrix  7180 x 10390.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [[0.85, 0.0], [0.2, 0.7], [0.0, 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['and', 'document']) 
output = df.apply(lambda x: list(x.dropna())).to_dict()

for k,v in output.items():
    print(f'{k}: {v}')
```

Output

```
and: [0.85, 0.2]
document: [0.7, 14.0]
```

Comment: your method works. I need to modify a bit the loop in this way `for word, dict in output.items(): for (dict, values) in dict.items(): if values > 0: print str(values) + ' ' +str(word.encode('utf8')) `
It works, but it take a lot of time. 8 minutes